# How many threads on each OpenGL pipeline state?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, glsl, gpu

How is the number of threads determined for the OpenGL pipeline at each stage?

By this I mean, say I have 2 programs:

In one I have 600 triangles, however these triangles are all at the same position and are so small that they get rasterized to a single pixel/

In the other I have only one triangle, but this triangle is larger than my screen, coloring every single pixel.

In the first case it would make sense for the vertex shader to have 600*3 threads and the fragment shader to have 1 thread.

In the second case it makes sense for the vertex shader to have only three threads and the fragment shader to have 1920*1080 threads.

However I do not think this is how thread are actually managed.

So how many threads actually get generated at each stage in the pipeline?

Is there any way to at least partially influence the number of generated threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know, you likely aren't able to control it, and it'd probably be a bad idea even if you could.

First and foremost, [the OpenGL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec44.core.pdf) only defines the functions you can call, parameters you use, and how they behave. Exactly *how* the OpenGL driver and GPU actually execute that is an implementation detail. GPU creators have developed a multitude of [extensions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/) for interfacing with their hardware out-of-spec, but I've yet to see one that does what you describe.

So an implementation *could* do exactly what you describe, but likely won't. There's a large number of variables that would affect thread allocation:

- available threads
- additional load (from other programs)
- shared resources
- historical calls (what inputs looked like in previous frames)
- historical shader performance (fragment shader speed vs vertex shader speed)
- etc.

However, a common implementation is to have pools of N threads that are designated dynamically to the separate pipeline stages based on the above variables. Meaning, if your fragment shaders take significantly more computation than your vertex shaders, more threads will likely be allocated to them in the future.

Comment: This answer is not good enough, I need the best idea I can get of how many threads will be lunched. If it has to be vendor specific then by vendor. But a number of threads will be created based on the input data and I need to know how many

Comment: There are profilers out there for all the major GPU vendors that would probably be your best bet for figuring it out, but I haven't seen a metric for this on NVidia NSight. Might I ask why you need such a specific metric?

Comment: I am doing a voxelizer for real time rendering, currently I am trying to figure out why an oct tree for logarithm lookup time is not working, in addition to a curious mysterious bug. This is based on an algorithm published in 2011 that claims the number of threads is equal to the number of vertices in glDrawArrays(), I am suspecting this is not true and that is part of the reason why the current algorithm is not working.

Comment: Interesting, though I can't fathom why an algorithm like that would be sensitive to threading (unless it was doing *really* fancy stuff). Either way, you should consider posting a question with your implementation to see if someone could catch your issue.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x You might also be confusing number of threads with number of invocations. If you have 600 vertices, then their is a very high chance that the vertex shader is executed 600 times (=600 invocations). But that doesn't necessarily mean that there are 600 threads. Leaving away the whole SIMD architecture stuff, there is no guarantee that these 600 invocations are done in parallel. For what you as a developer know, there could be just one thread invoking the vertex shader 600 times.

Comment: I guess it will be more productive if you ask in a new question about your specific problem. Show the code you have, explain what is happening and why you think that the number of threads is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of this conversation, I will assume that by "thread", you meant ["invocation"](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader#Execution_and_invocations). "Threads" don't exist in GLSL; only "invocations".

> In the first case it would make sense for the vertex shader to have 600*3 threads and the fragment shader to have 1 thread.

No, it would not.

The invocation frequency of the VS depends entirely on how you provided those triangles. For example, if they really are the same triangle, and you used an index buffer to fetch the same memory locations for each of the 3 vertices, then it is entirely possible for the VS to be executed exactly and only 3 times.

The fragment shader is even less well defined. Maybe the hardware realized that all of the potential rasterizer invocations will overwrite the same locations... and maybe it won't. Plus, most rasterizers will execute executing multiple invocations even if only one fragment from the triangle will be written. These hidden invocations are used to compute gradients for texture coordinates, and generally exist to make the common case run faster.

> In the second case it makes sense for the vertex shader to have only three threads and the fragment shader to have 1920*1080 threads.

It may run more than that.

In order for a single triangle to cover every pixel on the screen, that triangle will likely have to be larger than the guard-band of the renderer. Which means that the triangle will probably have to be clipped to the view volume.

So while the VS will produce a single triangle, the rasterizer will likely see 2 or even 3 triangles.

This means that there will be areas of overlap between the edges of these triangles, where those "hidden" FS invocations I talked about will exist. So you will likely have more FS invocations than you do pixels.

> So how many threads actually get generated at each stage in the pipeline?

You don't know. You *can't* know. And generally speaking, you should not be *trying* to know.

> Is there any way to at least partially influence the number of generated threads?

Yes: render more or less stuff. That will give you more or fewer invocations. That is all of the control OpenGL gives you, and it's all of the control you ought to need.